# c++ pass member function pointer as parameter

Tags: function, pointers, parameters

I've read quite a few posts member function pointer, but seems that none of the proposed solutions works in my case. I learnt how to declare member function pointer in those posts, so I have a class A like this:

```
Class A {
    // some members over here
    B  registar;

    int (A::cb) (int, void*);      // my function pointer

    int callback(int, void* args); // the function I need to call in method1()

    A(): cb(&A::callback) {}

    int method1()
    { 
        //need to access member variables here and construct args
        char* args;

        // this is where I need to pass callback(int, void*) as a parameter to somewhere.
        // what I want to achieve is something like 
        // registar.register(callback, args)
    } 
}
```

So I am trying to pass callback as a parameter to some function inside method1(), as indicated above.
How do I need to do this?

The example I looked at is

```
class A {
    public:
    int f();
     int (A::*x)(); // <- declare by saying what class it is a pointer to
};

int A::f() { return 1;}

int main() {
     A a;
     a.x = &A::f; // use the :: syntax
     printf("%d\n",(a.*a.x)()); // use together with an object of its class
}
```

I've tried the above syntax (this->(*this.cb)). it didn't work.

Comment: The error I got from registar.register(callback, args) is "error: reference to non-static member function must be called"

Comment: What's the definition of `register()`?

Comment: @Slaks By calling registar.register(), callback is registered with registar and will be called by registar later.